# Why do my js2-mode hooks work on Mac but not Fedora Linux?

Tags: init-file, hooks, js2-mode

I am getting very inconsistent behavior with `js-mode` and `js2-mode` hooks and I am not sure why.

I have three "hooks":

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mode-name "Zono-mode"))) 
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (tern-mode t)))
```

For some reason these **do** work on my Mac but do not work on my Fedora Linux system, and I am wondering if anyone can offer a reason as to why this would happen.

To further the strangeness, the very similar `(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda () (ac-js2-mode t)))` does work on both machines.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

All of the libaries have been installed, and, when opening a file that ends in `.js` I do enter `js2-mode` (it just seems none of the hooks are run)
The only possible difference I see is on my Fedora machine Emacs is 24.5.1 and on my Mac it is Emacs 24.4.1. but I looked and this should make no difference (in fact the newer versions should help make sure hooks are run)

Comment: To get the obvious question out of the way -- have you installed the `js2-mode` library on your Fedora machine? And if so, is it the same version which is working on your other machine?

Comment: sorry @phils I just updated the question. It is the same version as my other machine, everything except the emacs version number is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was called because `ac-js2` mode was being called and raising an error. Commenting it out fixed the problem.